# individual user services for moving local data?

Tags: c#

I have a client application that is used to maintain orders.  Users have the ability to run one-off reports from the application.  The reports are from from data which is created on the fly and saved to the individual user's pc.  The data is deleted when the application is closed.

There is a 2 step process in the app to create the report.  first, the report button is clicked, which creates the data in the local folder.  then the the create report button is clicked, at which time the report is actually created using that data.  As I said earlier, when the app is closed, all local data is deleted.

I have a need to collect this data so that it can be reported against.  Currently, I have the user stop after the first step mentioned above and manually run a short program which copies the local data to a network share where it can be processed.  I would like to eliminate the manual step of running the copy app.

How are people handling similar situations to this?  I have less than 10 users who would need it, and it can be run once a day, sometimes as many as 5 times a day.  I have considered creating a service to run locally on each users pc, but this seems like it would be difficult to maintain.  Can a windows service be pushed out by a login script?

Does anyone have any other thoughts regarding how this could be handled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a windows service with a FileSystemWatcher to detect when the files you want to save are created and then copy them to the network.

If the users have administrative rights on their local machines you can use a logon script to run a utility app to check if the service is installed and up-to-date and if not update.  As long as you have .NET 3.5 SP1 or later, intranet-based exe's will have the rights to install the service locally.  If either of these is not true you would need something more comprehensive like System Center Configuration Manager.

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager.aspx

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but it seems like a lot of maintenance to keep up with just a handful of users.  Also, the permissions get to become a pain as most are not local administrators.

Comment: @czuoski, I assume from the question that you can't just modify the application they use?  That of course would be the simplest solution.  Also,if it's just a handful of users then installing manually should be easy enough.  You don't even need an installer, use the command line service installation tools.

Comment: that's true - I do not have access to modify the original application.  I think manually installing is really my only option, so I can push forward with that.